# Bootstrap menu is not opened on Enter key, when the data-toggle is added to span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" >Dropdown Example</button>
    <span tabindex=0 class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a span element and it has a backgorund image search, on click of search button I open menu.
I don't need a button beside my search button, so I added data-toggle=dropdown to my span.
Dropdown menu is opened when I click with mouse, but menu is not opened when i get focus to span and press enter key on it.

```
Here it is reproducible
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajp1513/z264ykfL/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in the HTML. move the span inside the button tag and 
remove the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute form the span and add it to the button.

---

From

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" >Dropdown Example</button>
    <span tabindex=0 class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
```

To

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span tabindex=0 class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"></span></button>
```

Here is the full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span tabindex=0 class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```